# Initial data is not loading to the input field when ui-mask is added

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui

I have the below table,

```
<table class="me-checkbox-table">
    <thead>
    <th class="checkbox-column">
        <md-checkbox md-no-ink  aria-label="Check all"></md-checkbox>
    </th>
    <th>sku#</th>
    <th class="item-name-column">item name</th>
    <th class="id-column">qty</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>sale price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="inventory in inventoryList">
        <td class="checkbox-row">
            <md-checkbox md-no-ink  aria-label="Check one item"></md-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td ng-model="inventory.sku">{{inventory.sku}}</td>
        <td><a href="" ng-model="inventory.name" ng-click="gotoedit(inventory)">{{inventory.name}}</a></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+/" ui-mask="999" ng-model="inventory.quantity" />
        </td>
        <span class="error" ng-show="allItems.quantity.$error.minlength"></span>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="inventory.price" /></td>
        <td class="sale-yes"><input type="number" ng-model="inventory.discount" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get data from backend using controller and below is my controller,

```
inventoryService.getInventoryList()
                         .success(function (result) {

                             $scope.inventoryList = result;
                             console.log("result "+result[0]);
                         }).error(function (error) {
                             alert("Inventory Loading Error : " + error);
                         })
```

the value for Quantity is loading when I do not add ui-mask in the input field but When I do, it won't load data to the Quantity field. Please help

Comment: Could you please add following console.log to trace inventory.quantity: console.log("result "+result[0].quantity); ?

Comment: Data is coming from the back end and it is loading to other fields and when I remove the ui-mask part from the code, I can see the data is loaded to the Quantity input field

Comment: Why did you put '999' as pattern, that means that quantity should be from 100 to 999, else value will be rejected by validation? Did you mean that?

Comment: Or you can use values like this: 001, 002, ...

Comment: ui-mask means three dashed placeholders to put only three numbers and 999 means each dashed line can have 0-9. Please refer the documentation for angular ui-mask

Comment: Yes, but the problem is e.g. 70 will be rejected as value and you will not see result.

Comment: Just run sample from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [created sample](https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/y52vq2z0/) of mine on top of yours and here is what I found:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    {{ quantity }}
    <input type="text" name="quantity" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+/" ui-mask="999" ng-model="quantity" />
  </div>
</div>
```

When I assign values from 0 to 99, ui-mask rejects it and I see empty input.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.mask'])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.quantity = 70;
  });
```

When I assign values from 100 to 999 it works properly:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.mask'])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.quantity = 544;
  });
```